# What might be causing my results to print out in reverse of what they should?

Tags: java, binary, numbers, radix, base-conversion

This is my last lab of this set for while/do-while loops and I've got it all figured out aside from my result printing out in the exact reverse of what it should be.

```
public class TenToAny
{
private int base10;
private int newBase;

public TenToAny()
{

}

public TenToAny(int ten, int base)
{
   base10 = ten;
   newBase = base;
}

public void setNums(int ten, int base)
{
   base10 = ten;
   newBase = base;
}
public String getNewNum()
{
    String newNum="";
    int orig = base10;

    while(orig > 0)
    {
        newNum = orig%newBase + newNum;
        orig = orig/newBase;
    }
    return newNum;
}

public String toString()
{
    String complete = base10 + " base 10 is " + getNewNum() + " in base " + newBase;

    return complete;
}


}
```

here's what my results should be:

> 234 base 10 is 280 in base 9
>
> 100 base 10 is 1100100 in base 2

these are the expect results for the first two values (234 in base 9 AND 100 in binary)

Here's what I'm getting:

> 234 base 10 is 082 in base 9
>
> 100 base 10 is 0010011 in base 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're simply adding the end of the `newNum` instead of prepending.

```
newNum = newNum + orig%newBase;
```

... should be ...

```
newNum = orig%newBase + newNum;
```

For characters...

When `orig%newBase > 9`, then `char(55 + orig%newBase)`

```
var nextValue = orig % newBase;

if (nextValue > 9)
{
    newNum = char(55 + nextValue) + newNum;
}
else
{
    newNum = nextValue + newNum;
}
```

Comment: "250 base 10 is FA in base 16" is one of the expected answers....

how would I go about getting the letters for this code? I've never had to deal with letters when doing numeral bases

Comment: @tech_geek23:  updated the answer.  Also, for base 2,8,10,16:  [Convert.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx)

Comment: where in my code would this need to be placed? within the while loop?

Comment: would you mind editing my original code from this post to show me where it belongs? I don't quite follow what you're saying 100%

Comment: now i've got an error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Syntax error on token "char", delete this token"